# Как перевести mssql в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такой mssql запрос:

```
declare @start date = '2016-12-12'; -- Новая дата заезда
declare @end date = '2016-12-20'; -- Новая дата выезда
declare @today date = '2016-12-11';

update  main
set     numbernomer = null
where   datestart > @today;

declare @mainnumber int;

while exists (select * from main where numbernomer is null)
begin

    select top(1) @mainnumber = id
    from    main
    where   numbernomer is null
    order by datestart asc, datediff(day, datestart, dateend) desc;

    update m0
    set     numbernomer = m1.nomer
    from    main m0
            cross apply (SELECT top 1 a.nomer
                        FROM    allnomer a
                                LEFT JOIN main m
                                ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
                                AND DATEDIFF(day, m.datestart, m0.dateend) * DATEDIFF(day, m.dateend, m0.datestart) <= 0
                                left join (select m2.numbernomer, max(m2.dateend) as dateend from main m2 group by m2.numbernomer) as m2
                                        on a.nomer = m2.numbernomer
                        WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL
                        order by datediff(day, m2.dateend, m0.datestart), a.nomer
                        ) as m1
    where   m0.id = @mainnumber;

end;

SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m
  ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
  AND DATEDIFF(day, m.datestart, @end) * DATEDIFF(day, m.dateend, @start) <= 0
WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL;
```

Я пытаюсь перевести этот запрос на mysql. Я знаю, что нужно изменить decale на set, тип данных убрать и заменить top 1 на limit 1.всё... Подскажите, как перевести этот запрос на mysql? Что нужно изменить?

P.S. Запрос должен будет выполняться в этой таблице: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81225

Comment: написать запрос с нуля не пробовали?

Comment: @Anatol , ума не хватает(знаний)

Comment: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/ - сравнение различных синтаксисов

Comment: ну и [Google](https://google.com)

Comment: переписывать запрос вместо Вас что-то не хочется

Comment: @Anatol ошибка на ошибке... ради интереса, сколько это может стоить?

Comment: ну это напрямую зависит от исполнителя, разумеется